# Passing an oject's method to ajax - javascript only

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an object with two methods as shown:

```
function PendingRequests(){
    this.count;
    this.id = [];
    this.event = [];
}
PendingRequests.prototype.get = function(){
    var request_parameter = 'cont=pr';
    Ajax(url,request_parameter,this.get2);
}
PendingRequests.prototype.get2 = function(pr){
    this.count = pr.length;
    for(var i=0;i<this.count;i++){
        this.id[i]          = pr[i]['id'];
        this.event[i]       = pr[i]['event'];
    }
}
var pendingrequests = new PendingRequests();
```

and the ajax function

`Ajax(url,parameter,funct){...}`

which after getting a response calls the passed function

```
funct(JSON.parse(XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText));
```

the script executes until calling the method after ajax response, but then i get an error that **"this.id is undefined"**

Please help with this.

Comment: You're just passing a reference to a function (which happens to be on a prototype chain, but that means nothing when you're just referencing it), not the `pendingrequests` object which has it in its prototype.

Comment: You might not want this, but if you know this will be your structure (where `Ajax` will always only deal with a `PendingRequests` object, for example), you may want to pass `this` instead of `this.get2`, and then in your `Ajax` method, call `funct.get2` instead of `funct`

Answer (score 0):

You must assign a context to the function otherwise it will be called in the global context, you must accept another parameter in the ajax function:

```
Ajax(url,parameter,funct, context){...}
```

And then trigger the function using call:

```
funct.call(context, JSON.parse(XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText));
```

Then the call in the get function will be:

```
Ajax(url,request_parameter,this.get2, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I tried both suggestions, but was still getting the same error.

In the end i solved the issue.

I made the change Ian suggested. (even though the ajax function will also deal with other object, but for all of them i can define a get2 method)

Since it was still giving the error, i defined all the properties:

```
this.count;
this.id = [];
this.event = [];
```

in a different way:

```
PendingRequests.prototype.count = 0;
PendingRequests.prototype.id = [];
PendingRequests.prototype.event = [];
```

Now it's working... i will have just one PendingRequests object, so hope the prototyping will not give me any errors later.